# Which flush wins

Tags: flush

Sorry I know questions like this have been asked but I can't find anything on this specific hand. Who wins this hand:

Board is 9H 2C JH KH 6D

Player 1 shows QH 3H for the flush
Player 2 shows 10H 8H for the flush

Player 1 has the highest hole card but Player 2 has the 8 which beats the 2 held by Player 1. So who wins?

Comment: Hi Paul, the hands each player has are as follows: KhQhJh9h3h for player 1 and KhJhTh9h8h for player 2. Because player 1 has the queen, they have the highest flush and win the hand just as @David mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The strength of a flush is measured by the value of the highest card, then the second highest card.... and so on until the fifth.

The second highest card in player's 1 flush in a queen versus a jack in player 2's. Player 1 wins